# onclick load content, run a function and only then show

Tags: jquery, promise, load

I load() a container id=floor incl. a text-container from another page into
the container id=floor, execute the function 'layoutart()' (split text into pages and columns), and only then want the container to fade in.

The problem is: the moment I load the external container it'll show, some people add the function show() but it shows anyway - and thus too early:

So, on load, I get this flicker (text before layout-function)
I tried setTimeout, queue(function()), delay; promises I don't really
understand. Mostly because I have no plan:
I need the load()function to run before the layoutart()function,
and to show/fadeIn only after the layoutart()function.

```
$( 'a.art' ).click(function (e) {

     var href = $(this).attr('href') + ' #floor';

     $('#floor').hide().load( href, function(){

         $(this).layoutart();
         $(this).fadeIn();

     });

     return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.get` with `append`

```
$.get(href, function(page) {
         $('#floor').append($(page).find('#floor'));
         $('#floor').hide();
         layoutart();
         $('#floor').fadeIn();
     });
```

Comment: thanks but I get the exact same effect -?Any other idea?

Comment: I'm just realizing I'm not loading #floor, but the whole page, probably default link, so far sorry, will be back when found error

Comment: there are two problems: first, if I replace $(this).layout( ) by $(this).css('background-color' , 'blue') nothing happens. But it turns blue for $(this).children( ).css(..); Second: $(this).children( ).layout( ) doesn't work anyway. The code above I have wrapped into a document ready function and below that I have: function layout( ){ // do stuff }; there is some calling problem I don't get. I tried $.fn.layout( ){ } instead, doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: why are you attaching the layout function to a jquery object?why not call it directly ?how does `layout` look like?

Comment: sorry for answering so late - got lost; I'm bad at js so: what is jquery object vs call directly? as for layout(), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57370327/jquery-dynamic-page-break-not-after-heading; as for my current problem, I've come to understand if you load with a selector, the content will be stripped of all scripts; I'd appreciate any help

Comment: as for calling the function directly:= layout(); in an extra line?? - then the script will load the whole page and not the container #content

Comment: for var href=$(this).attr('href') the floor in my page will disappear but nothing else will happen (blank page); I had this effect for load() too, when I called layout() on $(this); website: www.politicaleconomics.net